# Get the var from url

Tags: wordpress

I have url like this:

```
index.php?category_name=$matches[1]/$matches[2]&var1=yes&paged=$matches[3]
```

and I want to get var1 from this url, how to do it?

Regards

Comment: Why are you passing `var1=yes` statically instead of a dynamic value?

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve public query variable in the WP_Query class of the global $wp_query object.

**Usage**

```
<?php get_query_var( $var, $default ) ?>
```

**Parameters**

$var
 The variable key to retrieve.

**Example**

```
// Test if the query exists at the URL
if ( get_query_var('var1') ) {

    // If so echo the value
    echo get_query_var('var1');

}
```

**Get URL Variable**

```
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
echo $query['var1'];
```

Comment: My url really looks: pagename.com/category1/category2/var1, when I get var1 it gives me value YES, but i want the name of var1